# Pass data viewcontroller to NSObject

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsobject

I'm having a little problem on a project.
The project begins with a view that the User selects an account (ACAccount). Problem is how to send the account selected by the User to an NSObject.

Example:

ViewControllerGetAccounts(select Account)     ->   NSObject(load data)   ->    ViewControllerViewDataOfAccount(show data).

Answer (score -1):

Your give your NSObject subclass a public method, something like

```
  - (myData*)loadData:(id)accountID;
```

So you can send a loadData: message to the object from your viewController and - assuming you have correctly defined your `loadData:` method - expect to receive back some `myData*` data.

In your viewController:

```
  MyData* myData = [myObject loadData:accountID];
```

Now you have the data, you can do what you want with it.

Comment: and send data to NSObject?

Comment: your NSObject subclass is myObject... you are sending the accountID to myObject, and getting the required data back from myObject.

Comment: selector accounts is a UITableView. method in which I do this?

Comment: and how do I do to add the account in the array "+ (NSArray)"